# R shiny deal with missing input

Tags: r, shiny, visualization, shinydashboard

I made a application with R Shiny and I would like to be able to set all combinations when input is missing without having to write IF... ELSE IF... for each combination.
For example, when the "name" input is empty, I'd like to have the theme input crossed with the survey input and the question input. I've tried several things that don't work.

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$results <- renderDataTable({
    if (is.null(input$nameSelect) & is.null(input$themeSelect) & is.null(input$SURVEYSelect)  & is.null(input$questionSelect)){return(NULL)}
    if (!is.null(input$nameSelect) & !is.null(input$themeSelect) & !is.null(input$surveySelect)  & !is.null(input$questionSelect)){
      dt <- data %>%
        filter(VARIABLE %in% input$nameSelect & THEME %in% input$themeSelect & SURVEY %in% input$surveySelect & QUESTIONNAIRE %in% input$questionSelect)
      dt
    }
```

it works only if all combinations match...

Comment: Maybe check if inputs actually return NULL when empty. Some inputs return `""` instead of null. You can also use `require` at the beginning of Shiny reactive objects to ensure the object only runs if requirements are met, like a certain object existing (`require(object)`), or a condition like `require(input$nameSelect != "")`

Comment: But sorry I'm new beginner with shiny, I'm not sure I understand. Where should I put this condition?

Comment: As the first line of your `renderDataTable` object. For example, if you write `output$results <- renderDataTable({ require(input$nameSelect != "") print("hello") })`, the "hello" message will not be printed until the input has content.

Comment: OK so I have this : 
`    require(input$nameSelect != "")
    if (is.null(input$nameSelect) & is.null(input$themeSelect) & is.null(input$SURVEYSelect)  & is.null(input$questionSelect)){return(NULL)}

    if (!is.null(input$nameSelect) & !is.null(input$themeSelect) & !is.null(input$SURVEYSelect)  & !is.null(input$questionSelect)){
      dt <- data %>%
        filter(VARIABLE %in% input$nameSelect & THEME %in% input$themeSelect & SURVEY %in% input$SURVEYSelect & QUESTIONNAIRE %in% input$questionSelect)
      dt
    }`
and the error the condition has length > 1

Comment: if input$nameSelect is empty, I want the table to show the other crossed inputs and the condition &.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, the function is `req`, not `require`! Furthermore, you don't need to check if all inputs are not null is you already are stopping the execution when all are null. Also, maybe you want to stop execution if one of all inputs are null, but not others? In that case, use the "or" operator: `|`. Other than that, I don't understand what "theme input crossed with the survey input and the question input" means.

Comment: thank you for your reply! On the contrary, I want to continue execution when one or more inputs are null. And also make the data displayed correspond to input1 AND input2 AND input3 AND input4 even if one has not been filled in (that's what I meant by crossed with. sorry for my English x)

Comment: I would suggest you to create a new reactive object that runs the logic that outputs a certain “state” you want to use further on your data visualization, like have all the ifs inside a reactive that outputs a string of text like “data without name”, “data with name but without theme”, etc., so that you simplify your code and also you can reuse that logic on other reactives